# Passing shared_ptr as parameter in async call

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, future

I am converting my code to multi thread to performance enhancement.

I have vector of shared_ptr and an object of another class and I am passing a shared_ptr from vector and an object as parameter to function. 
I am calling it using std::async but it is giving me following error :

```
line from where I am making async call : required from here 
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional1697.61: error: no type named 'type' 
in 'class std::result_of<void (*(std::shared_ptr<A>, B))
(const  std::shared_ptr<A>&, B&)>'typedef typename 
result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
```

Here is code snippet :

```
void foo(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>& a, B b){
    std::vector<std::future<void>> tasks;
    for(auto& sptr : a ){
        tasks.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, foo1, a, b))
    }

 void foo1(const std::shared_ptr<A>& a, B& b ){
    //do some stuff
 }
```

Can you please help me. Thanks

Comment: @Piotr thank you for editing it. It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am converting my code to multi thread to performance enhancement.

Here we go ... I predict difficulties.

The error is telling you that the result of calling `foo1` with the arguments that `std::async` will pass to it is not defined, i.e. you can't call the function with those arguments.

The reason is that the function `foo1` takes a parameter of type `B&` but `std::async` copies its arguments and forwards the *copies* to the target function, so it is going to copy `b` and then call `foo1` with that copy forwarded as an rvalue, which cannot be bound to an lvalue reference of type `B&`.

If you really want to pass `b` by reference then you need to wrap it:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, foo1, a, std::ref(b))
```

However you should be careful, it looks like every thread is going to have a non-const reference to the same `B` object, implying they might be modifying that object concurrently, which will lead to data races (and undefined behaviour) unless `B` is already thread-safe or you modify the function `foo1` to synchronize access to `B`.

Just sprinkling multithreaded pixie dust on your code is not going to make it faster if the code is not safe to use in multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan, I thought error was in shared_ptr but it was in B object. and thank you for pointing out issue it is coming with it. I will definitely consider this.

Comment: This-- "Just sprinkling multithreaded pixie dust on your code is not going to make it faster if the code is not safe to use in multiple threads." -- is absolute truth! Trying to multithread spaghetti code can actually make your performance worse. Using the proper data structures and algorithms, loose coupling, and good locality of reference is far more important.